# How do I run a Bootstrap affix function on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this function that calculates offsets and styles for the menu I want to affix using Bootstrap affix plugins:

http://jsfiddle.net/jssdfqfp/

```
function MyAffix(options) {
  var e = options.element,
      eWidth = e.width(),
      eOffsetTop = e.offset().top;

  // Calculate offsets

  e.affix({
    offset: {
      top: function() {
        return (this.top = eOffsetTop - 40);
      },
      bottom: function() {
        return (this.bottom = $("footer").outerHeight(true));
      }
    }
  });

  // Apply styles

  e.on({

    "affixed.bs.affix": function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "width": eWidth,
        "top": 40
      })
    },
    "affixed-top.bs.affix": function() {
      $(this).attr("style", "");
    }

  });

}

var uiMenuAffix = new MyAffix({element: $("#ui-menu")});
```

which seems to be working OK.

What I want is to make it update the data on window resize. I am relatively new to JS, so I am not really sure where I should run the $(window).resize() function and what should I put in it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        returnUIMenuAffix();
    });
});


function returnUIMenuAffix()
{
    var uiMenuAffix = new MyAffix({element: $("#ui-menu")});
    return uiMenuAffix;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gswhuza6/4/)